# ASP.NET MVC 5 - HttpClient 0.3.0 not found in Nuget Package Manager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nuget, .net-4.8, nuget-package-manager-console

I'm trying to update my app's .NET framework version to 4.8 and executed the Update-Package command

but it gets error pointed to HttpClient package

[image: nuget error screenshot]

I couldn't find this package when trying to search it on Nuget Package Manager

https://www.nuget.org/packages/HttpClient/0.3.0

[image]

It doesn't event say this library is deprecated or obsolette when I look up on its detail

Is there something I need to do to be able to make it show in the Nuget Package Manager browse list?

Comment: sorry, I just saw the message from the package info itself that this is not in use anymore because of vulnerabilities. will answer my own question after I am able to

Comment: From the link in your question: "*The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package is deprecated, has security vulnerabilities or shouldn't be used anymore.*"

Comment: See bottom of following page.  The HttpClient is still validh(ttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?force_isolation=true&view=net-5.0 ).  Did you do a clean build after changing Net Version?

Comment: @jdweng yes, I did but I still encounter the issue

Comment: I think the link you have is System.Net.Http.HttpClient; the HttpClient I refer to is in this nuget link (https://www.nuget.org/packages/HttpClient/0.3.0) that says "The owner has unlisted this package...."