# Nuget Package Manager - Update-Package NotSpecified error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nuget

I am trying to update my app's package to be compatible with .NET Framework 4.8

After I execute the Update-Package nuget command, I get an error mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67806458/asp-net-mvc-5-httpclient-0-3-0-not-found-in-nuget-package-manager?noredirect=1#comment119854095_67806458)

Then after solving that issue, when I execute again the Update-Package, I'm now getting this error:

```
Executing nuget actions took 10.93 min
Update-Package : This collection is read-only.
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-Package -Reinstall -verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UpdatePackageCommand
```

I don't know where to check this because it didn't say which library or files are affected by this error.

I tried to clean the packages, enabled verbose flag and everything that was suggested to the search but to no luck

Has somebody encountered the same and overcome this issue?

Really need help on this one.

Comment: There is a link on your old posting that show HttpClient.  It looks like when you updated your Net version and recompiled the Updating of the Project did not complete.  So when you tried to compile after the initial failure not all the libraries got update to the latest version.  Now the project is looking for an older version of HttpClient than what is installed on your machine.  I would find the reference to the HttpClient and delete from the build instructions.  Then if you still fail add back the reference.  This will change version to the version of the library you have installed.

Comment: I already deleted the "HttpClient" from my app.config and web.config..it just keeps on displaying the error

Comment: it is not the call to the HttpClient that is the issue.  it is the reference that you have in the project to the library.  You have to delete the reference.  Open up Solution Explorer in VS and delete the reference.